how to remove Conda from computer if I accidentally downloaded it to "all users"
I am new to coding so please let me know how I can better phrase my question... thank you.
I need to make a Conda environment for a project I am working on, I decided to download Miniconda because this is my first project so I wanted bare bones environment. I downloaded the python 3.11 package version (https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py311_24.4.0-0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg) for Mac. I followed the prompts and installed it "for all users". I did not fully realize what this meant (I am new to computers). with further research afterwords I realized I wanted to download a different version.
the link above with the Miniconda is the only thing I downloaded, I cannot remove it I have no idea how to. I have logged onto the administration of my terminal and when I % ls, I can see "Conda" and I can Conda --help and get information about it but I have no idea how to uninstall it. When I try to % cd into Conda, no file exists, so there is no file for me to remove.
cd/opt/miniconda
sh: cd/opt/miniconda: No such file or directory

I went to my user profile on admin mode
/user/"my name"
sh-3.2# ls
... conda (conda appears on the list)
sh-3.2# conda --help
conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications, environments and packages.

options:
  -h, --help          Show this help message and exit.
  -v, --verbose       Can be used multiple times. Once for detailed output, twice for INFO
                      logging, thrice for DEBUG logging, four times for TRACE logging.
  --no-plugins        Disable all plugins that are not built into conda.
  -V, --version       Show the conda version number and exit.

commands:
  The following built-in and plugins subcommands are available.

  COMMAND
    activate          Activate a conda environment.
    clean             Remove unused packages and caches.
    compare           Compare packages between conda environments.
    config            Modify configuration values in .condarc.
    content-trust     Signing and verification tools for Conda
    create            Create a new conda environment from a list of specified packages.
    deactivate        Deactivate the current active conda environment.
    doctor            Display a health report for your environment.
    export            Export a given environment
    info              Display information about current conda install.
    init              Initialize conda for shell interaction.
    install           Install a list of packages into a specified conda environment.
    list              List installed packages in a conda environment.
    notices           Retrieve latest channel notifications.
    package           Create low-level conda packages. (EXPERIMENTAL)
    remove (uninstall)
                      Remove a list of packages from a specified conda environment.
    rename            Rename an existing environment.
    repoquery         Advanced search for repodata.
    run               Run an executable in a conda environment.
    search            Search for packages and display associated information using the
                      MatchSpec format.
    update (upgrade)  Update conda packages to the latest compatible version.
sh-3.2# rm conda
rm: conda: No such file or directory

I have tried many things but I just really honestly do not know what I am doing. I apologize if this isn't enough information, please help me get this off my computer.
P.S. I have removed some sensitive information with black squaresadministrative command prompt window with conda in my user ls and attempt at rm it
I thought if I navigated to Conda and did a rm command it would be uninstalled or removed, I thought it was a file or directory. I am not sure if I need to do a different command or what I need to do to get it off, but I do not want to have the (base) if I don't even have a functioning environment to navigate to. otherwise it just takes up space. I asked chat GPT to no avail to help me remove it, it keeps mentioning packages that seem to not exist, otherwise, would rm not work? do I need to use an uninstall command?

Not sure if it's your entire problem, but cd/opt/miniconda is missing a space (should presumably be cd /opt/miniconda)

Did you try to google for "uninstall miniconda macos"?
